# SQL Server: Selecting XML fields with HTML values

Tags: html, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a pre-built ecomm module for a website that is storing HTML in an XML field in SQL.

That being said when I select data from that field it's all jargon instead of my HTML.

How can I recode the XML into HTML in a select statement?

Data Stored in xml field [Overview]:

```
<locale en-US="&lt;h3&gt;As Shown Details&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;p&gt;6514/1 SN AWH TABLE LAMP AS SHOWN&lt;/p&gt; &lt;h3&gt;Item Details&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;table-responsive&quot;&gt;  &lt;table class=&quot;table table-striped table-condensed&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; border=&quot;0&quot;&gt;   &lt;tbody&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Manufacturer&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;Holtkotter International&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Dimensions&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;Width 7.25 x Depth 7.25 x Height 18.5&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Seat Height&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Arm Height&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Inside Depth&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Fabric Content&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Country of Origin&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;   &lt;/tbody&gt; &lt;/table&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;part1&quot;&gt;This modern table lamp adds style and versatility to virtually any decor. Equipped with a full-range, turn-knob dimmer and a 100 Watt Halogen bulb by Osram. Pair it with the matching wall sconce 9426, floor lamp 6515, or swing-arm floor lamp 9434.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;part2&quot;&gt;Available in Hand Brushed Old Bronze (shown), Antique Brass, Brushed Brass, Chrome, and Satin Nickel Finishes.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;part3&quot;&gt;Halogen Line Voltage 100W bulb included.&lt;/div&gt;" />
```

Should be clean HTML I've tried using

```
select convert(xml, [Overview]) as code
from [mytable]
for xml path (''), type
```

but it returns

```
<code><locale en-US="&lt;h3&gt;As Shown Details&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;p&gt;6514/1 SN AWH TABLE LAMP AS SHOWN&lt;/p&gt; &lt;h3&gt;Item Details&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;table-responsive&quot;&gt;  &lt;table class=&quot;table table-striped table-condensed&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; border=&quot;0&quot;&gt;   &lt;tbody&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Manufacturer&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;Holtkotter International&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Dimensions&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;Width 7.25 x Depth 7.25 x Height 18.5&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Seat Height&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Arm Height&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Inside Depth&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Fabric Content&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Country of Origin&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;   &lt;/tbody&gt; &lt;/table&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;part1&quot;&gt;This modern table lamp adds style and versatility to virtually any decor. Equipped with a full-range, turn-knob dimmer and a 100 Watt Halogen bulb by Osram. Pair it with the matching wall sconce 9426, floor lamp 6515, or swing-arm floor lamp 9434.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;part2&quot;&gt;Available in Hand Brushed Old Bronze (shown), Antique Brass, Brushed Brass, Chrome, and Satin Nickel Finishes.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;part3&quot;&gt;Halogen Line Voltage 100W bulb included.&lt;/div&gt;" /></code>
```

Comment: Perhaps some sample data and desired results would help

Comment: Hi @JohnCappelletti i've just added some data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to do any manual re-codings. Reading the *attribute* value directly from the XML will do all the re-encoding for you implicitly:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(Overview XML);
INSERT INTO @mockup(Overview) 
    VALUES(N'<locale en-US="&lt;h3&gt;As Shown Details&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;p&gt;6514/1 SN AWH TABLE LAMP AS SHOWN&lt;/p&gt; &lt;h3&gt;Item Details&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;table-responsive&quot;&gt;  &lt;table class=&quot;table table-striped table-condensed&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; border=&quot;0&quot;&gt;   &lt;tbody&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Manufacturer&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;Holtkotter International&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Dimensions&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;Width 7.25 x Depth 7.25 x Height 18.5&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Seat Height&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Arm Height&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Inside Depth&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Fabric Content&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;     &lt;tr&gt;       &lt;th scope=&quot;row&quot;&gt;Country of Origin&lt;/th&gt;       &lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;     &lt;/tr&gt;   &lt;/tbody&gt; &lt;/table&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;part1&quot;&gt;This modern table lamp adds style and versatility to virtually any decor. Equipped with a full-range, turn-knob dimmer and a 100 Watt Halogen bulb by Osram. Pair it with the matching wall sconce 9426, floor lamp 6515, or swing-arm floor lamp 9434.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;part2&quot;&gt;Available in Hand Brushed Old Bronze (shown), Antique Brass, Brushed Brass, Chrome, and Satin Nickel Finishes.&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;part3&quot;&gt;Halogen Line Voltage 100W bulb included.&lt;/div&gt;" />')

SELECT m.Overview.value(N'(/locale/@en-US)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @mockup AS m
```

The result can not be casted to XML due to the less strict rules of HTML (namely the unclosed `<br>` elements). But it works perfectly. Embedded in a website the browser showed me this
(**important** Your CSS classes are missing of course...):

[image]

Comment: @JohnCappelletti One (related) hint. There's no need to re-encode entities with `REPLACE`. Try this: `DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100)='&lt;SomeEvilXml attr="This &amp;amp; that"/&gt;';
SELECT CAST('<x>' + @s + '</x>' AS XML).value(N'.','nvarchar(max)');`. The main advantage: If there is an unexpected entity, your `REPLACE` cascade will not catch it...

Comment: I see that now.  My first attempt failed so I got bull-headed and forced it.  I really should have taken a moment to consider it further.  I would tell my kids (and staff), "There's no need to rush the wrong answer."